# Bluetooth connection is hanged on first Bluetooth dongle (Android App)

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I have a problem while working with multiple devices connected via BT LE (Bluetooth low energy).

Work flow is as below:
[image]

Step of processing:
1. Scan all bluetooth devices to get address.

```
BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = ((BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE)).getAdapter();
BluetoothLeScanner bluetoothLeScanner = mBtAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                .build();
if (btAdapter .isEnabled()) {
    bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
}
```

2.Loop all devices get by step 1. For each device:

```
BluetoothDevice btDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt = mBluetoothDevice.connectGatt(context, false, btCallback);
```

on onConnectionStateChange() of btCallBack I call bluetoothGatt .discoverServices(); when connection state is STATE_CONNECTED.

After doing data exchange with device. I call

```
bluetoothGatt.disconnect();
Thread.sleep(500);
bluetoothGatt.close();
```

Process next device

The problem is when I called bluetoothGatt.disconnect() and bluetoothGatt.close() but the first Bluetooth Dongle connection always hangs and the blue led of bluetooth dongle never blink even I kill the app.

Only the last Bluetooth dongle can release connection when work is done.

My question is why I call disconnect() and close() but it does not work ?

build.gradle: minSdkVersion 21, targetSdkVersion 28

Otherwise, this problem only occurs with some kind of Android devices not all devices. For example it works well on Samsung device (Android 7), but not working on other devices.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot. I fixed this problem by adding idle time between ICUs connection.

Step as below.
1. Connect to device 1
2. Transfer data
3. Disconnect device 1
4. Thread.sleep for some seconds
5. Connect to device 2
...

Hope this helps someone has problem as me.